# Cant transfer QVector<double> between server and client using QTcpSocket and QDataStream

Tags: c++, qt

I have server and client app on my local computer and I wanna transfer small double vector between them.
Ive tried to do tihs on server:

```
if (socket != nullptr)
{
    QByteArray data;
    QDataStream out(data);
    out.setDevice(socket);
    out << 1.6;
    socket->write(data);
    socket->flush();
}
```

and this on client:

```
double a = -2.;
if (socket != nullptr)
{
    socket->readAll();
    in.setDevice(socket);
    in >> a;
}
```

and i get 0 on client side instead of 1.6

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you facing? Please visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read the section [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: _@Sunny_ Good luck with getting your question out of its current status.

Comment: don't call `socket->readAll()` before using `QDataStream`. `QDataStream` will take care of reading the correct number of bytes from the socket. When it tries to do so in the code you posted, it doesn't find anything in the socket (since you've already called `readAll()`)

Comment: Also, make sure that the client-side snippet in your question is called when the socket's `readyRead()` signal is fired (i.e. it is located in a slot connected to the mentioned signal)...

Comment: QDataStream out(data); correct is -> QDataStream out(&data);

Comment: @Taz742, if I do this,      ' QByteArray data;
        QDataStream out(&data);' i get  'no matching function for call to 'QDataStream::QDataStream(QByteArray*)'
         QDataStream out(&data)'

Comment: try: QDataStream out(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);

Comment: &data + QIODevice::WriteObly... Copy and paste QDataStream out(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly)

Answer (score -1):

For this task Server should looks like this:
[Server.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljkdO.png)

[Server.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6T1a.png)

And client should be looking like this:
[Client.h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mX7z.png)
[Client.cpp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53WBC.png)

Comment: Just as with questions, any code associated with an answer should be *in* the answer -- not accessed via a link.  Also note that your client code still does no error checking and simply assumes that the conversion to `double` was successful